# Select if condition matches with only one specific value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query where I am trying to select the name of the user if (s)he has a spesific role. But I want it to be selected, if and only if (s)he has **only** the targeted spesific role, not with the other spesified roles(such as General Manager and Purchase Manager).

```
 DepartmentManagerName = (from r in efDB.TBL_TABNET_REL_USER_ROLE
                          where (h.Confirm_By == r.TBL_USER.ID) && r.TBL_TABNET_DEF_ROLE.ID == (int)Enums.UserRank.Manager
                          select r.TBL_USER.Name + " " + r.TBL_USER.Surname).FirstOrDefault(),
```

One user can have multiple roles in the table, such as being "Department Manager" and "General Manager" together. Here is the example from the table `TBL_TABNET_DEF_ROLE`;

```
ID UserID RoleID 
123  40    2    
126  40    5    
127  36    2    
128  42    2    
129  49    2    
130  55    2    
131  59    2    
132  61    2    
133  76    2    
134  77    2
```

But when I am assigning to the `DepartmentManagerName` variable, I don't want it to be assigned if the user has also the "General Manager" role. Because of the reason "Department Manager" role comes earlier than "General Manager" role in the database table, the where condition is being true and the user name is assigned to `DepartmentManagerName` variable even in next iterations it will be identified that user also has the role of "General Manager". But I want to achieve that there will be no assignment if any other role matched other than "Department Manager". How could I achieve that?

Comment: @MongZhu, the thing is that the linq query iterates over the table line by line. The different roles defined for user is never being on the same line, so I can't use a logical operator over there. I need to apply the logic after all of the iterations are over and then, there will be a check if there was 2 different matches and what where they. I am lost how Can I apply this logic with LINQ.

Comment: Have you tried to GroupBy UserId and then check the RoleId ?

Comment: @GuilhemPrev, I don't know how to take advantage of GroupBy in my problem.

Comment: So you would need to group by the data, filter those having count > 1, and get the row you would need. SQL version of what you would need is `... group by UserID having count(id) = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of something like this to solve your problem, it will get the UserId of the first user that have only one role and the RoleId == 2 (in my example).

```
public static void Main()
{
    var table = new List<TBL_USER>
    {
        new TBL_USER(1, 1, 1),
        new TBL_USER(2, 1, 2),
        new TBL_USER(3, 2, 1),
        new TBL_USER(5, 4, 1),
        new TBL_USER(6, 4, 2),
        new TBL_USER(7, 5, 1),
        new TBL_USER(8, 5, 2),
        new TBL_USER(9, 5, 3)
    };

    var user = table
        .GroupBy(tbl => tbl.UserId) // Group the lines with the same UserId
        .Where(grp => grp.Any(u => u.RoleId == 1) && grp.All(u => u.RoleId != 2)) // Get the groups that have a RoleId as 1 and not RoleId as 2
        .FirstOrDefault().Key; // Get the first group and get the Key (UserId)
}

public class TBL_USER
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public TBL_USER(int id, int user, int role)
    {
        Id = id;
        UserId = user;
        RoleId = role;
    }
}
```

Comment: im quite concerned about the `FirstOrDefault.Property` you have put, if its null, it will cause error, might I suggest a checker on the `FirstOrDefault` before getting the property

Comment: what i meant in the `where` if the `RoleId` is assured, might i suggest `First`

Comment: @GabLlorico They will probably never have null value in the RoleId column but a check is never a bad option. Thanks, I edit the answer

Comment: If `grp.Count() == 1`, you should be using `grp.First().RoleId == 2`. And, if there are groups, it's guaranteed to have 1 and only one item.

Comment: @PauloMorgado If I do this, it can fire an exception if the grp is empty. That's why I put FirstOrDefault()?.RoleId

Comment: No! because you've asserted that `grp` has 1 element.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Yes true, it was a habit, but I don't think there is a real interest to put First instead of FirstOrDefault. Maybe if he change the condition and forgot to do a FirstOrDefault.

Comment: The user can have different roles, so `grp.Count()` will eliminate necessary users. The user only can't have "Department Manager" and "General Manager" together. I need to check that.

Comment: @OzanYurtsever Ok I didn't understand your question like this, I update my answer to match your needs

Comment: @GuilhemPrev is there a way to get back name and surname from this query(Assume there is name and surname fields in TBL_USER table) instead of the key?

Comment: @GuilhemPrev that's just an excuse for sloppy code. Isn't it?

Comment: @OzanYurtsever Yes you can do a Select instead of the Key